# MATLAB: Conversion from symbolic data type to numeric data type

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

```
clear x;                             %line 1
syms x;                              %line 2
syms expression2                     %line 3
expression2 = taylor(exp(x),6,0.245) %line 4
x = 0.49;                            %line 5            
expression2                          %line 6
```

I when I put (line4)

```
expression2 = taylor(exp(x),6,0.245)
```

I have

```
expression2 =
exp(49/200)+exp(49/200)*(x-49/200)+1/2*exp(49/200)*(x-49/200)^2+1/6*exp(49/200)*(x-49/200)^3+1/24*exp(49/200)*(x-49/200)^4+1/120*exp(49/200)*(x-49/200)^5
```

Then when I put line6 after putting line 5 I hope get a numeric value (the result of replacing x in the expression of line 4) but I get  the return of line 4 again.
Can I replace the x in a particular expression?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [subs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/subs.html) for substitution in symbolic expression:

```
subs(expression2, 'x', x)
```

or when used after 'line 5':

```
subs(expression2)
```